# oracle PL/SQL function/procedure call with &-sign prefixed parameters

Tags: plsql

I came across **PL/SQL** function/procedure calls with &-sign prefixed parameters, for example `m_package.DeleteDuplicates(&param1, &parma2)` . Can someone tell me what does this & prefix imply.

Comment: It's not a PL/SQL  thing, it's a SQL*Plus parameter: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB

Answer (score 2):

> Hello "&" means it will ask user to input the input params to the
>   Procedure of Function.Hope below snippet helps

```
Example

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_av1(
    param1 IN NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(param1);
END;
```

> While execution it will prompt user to input param value

```
EXEC proc_av1(&input);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was helpfull.  The documentation says "When SQL*Plus encounters an undefined substitution variable in a command, SQL*Plus prompts you for the value." Does that mean if there is already a variable with that name then it will not prompt?